# What algorithm to use in selecting specific text from SMS

Tags: java, android, maps, android-developer-api

I'am trying to get create this app, that pick up a location address from SMS.
The phone will recive an ordered SMS like this:

"
POZAR - PADLO DREVO NA ELKT. ZICE, RECENJAK 38 --Posilja ReCO
-112, RIC:0000000, IL:0000000
"

In this case the "RECENJAK 38" is the address. Now I already created the brodcastReciver to read and store incoming SMS and I have done some methods that pick up address (my code now is selecting a text between , and --), but my problem is that this SMS dont come in this order all the time.

I was thinking if it were possible that the sms would compere with the database of addresses

Five possible formats:

1: POZAR - (reason)-sometext, address -- Posilja: ReCO...(text after -- isnt 
   important)

2: AED, address, sometext --Posilja: ReCO...

3: address - (reason)sometext --Posilja: ReCO...

Comment: SMS order is dependent on the service provider and other factors, you have zero control over it. Why dont you just add a different number to the beginning of each text so that you know which one was sent first based on the number that the text contains?

Comment: No, my problem isnt that. My problom is that I dont know how would I select a specific text from SMS text, like in my example I want to automatically select just "RECENJAK 38" and assign to another string

Comment: You can just parse the string, what are the identifiers that show you that RECENJAK 38 is the part that you want?

Comment: Thats the problem, this sms are send by some other aplication for firefighters and sms comes in plain text. Most of the time they send it in order that the location address in between , and --, and I manage to solve it, but sometime they also send it in different and my method doesn't work :/

Comment: How many other ways are the texts sent in as?

Comment: like 5 different ways

Comment: So just build a algorithm that checks which of the five formats its in, and parses the string using one of 5 different methods

Comment: I will try to make this, dont know how yet but I will try

Comment: If you want, post all of the five possible formats, and I can try to help you create the parser

Comment: Add it to the question

Comment: Ok thank you, I realize there are 3 important formats